# Build and use static library in Android NDK

Tags: android-ndk, native-activity

I'm trying to build a library for my NativeActivity app and use it, but it is giving me an error:

Having these files:

```
-jni/
--android.mk
--application.mk
--main.cpp
--png/
---android.mk
---lodepng.c
---lodepng.h
```

The android.mk in `jni/png/` is this:

```
LOCAL_PATH  := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := lodepng
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := lodepng.c
# LOCAL_C_INCLUDES  := $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -DLODEPNG_NO_COMPILE_ENCODER -DLODEPNG_NO_COMPILE_DISK -DLODEPNG_NO_COMPILE_ANCILLARY_CHUNKS -DLODEPNG_NO_COMPILE_CPP

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

And the android.mk in `jni/` is this:

```
LOCAL_PATH  := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := myapp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.cpp
# LOCAL_C_INCLUDES  := $(LOCAL_PATH)/png
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -DANDROID
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog -landroid -lEGL -lGLESv1_CM
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES  := lodepng android_native_app_glue

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(LOCAL_PATH)/png/android.mk

$(call import-module,android/native_app_glue)
```

(I have commented the C_INCLUDES as I'm not sure I need them. Using them or not has no difference in the result).

The error I get when I try to compile it, is this one:

```
C:\workspace\myapp> C:\cygwin\bin\bash --login -c "ndk-build -C ."
Compile++ thumb  : myapp <= main.cpp
Compile thumb  : lodepng <= lodepng.c
StaticLibrary  : liblodepng.a
SharedLibrary  : libmyapp.so
C:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/..
/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe:
 ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/myapp/main.o: in function init():jni/main.cpp:194:
 error: undefined reference to 'lodepng_decode32(unsigned char**, unsigned int*,
 unsigned int*, unsigned char const*, unsigned int)'
C:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/..
/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe:
 ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/myapp/main.o: in function init():jni/main.cpp:196:
 error: undefined reference to 'lodepng_error_text(unsigned int)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libmyapp.so] Error 1
```

In resume, it is like if the code could't find the header, of this lib. Nevertheless, It does compile, so that is not the problem...

What should I edit so I can make use of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing C++ name mangling is problem here. Your lodepng.c file provides `_lodepng_decode32` symbol (as it is compiled as C code), but your main.cpp file expects something like `_lodepng_decode32$asdaASd` symbol (because it is compiled as C++ code).

You should rename `lodepng.c` to `lodepng.cpp`.

Or you need to put `#include "lodepng.h"` in your `main.cpp` file inside `extern "C" { ... } block`.

Comment: It was that indeed! I'm shocked how a simple extension name can make such problem on an Android Code. Thanks a lot! I'll be more careful with that from now on! :)

Comment: @Mārtiņš Možeiko Can you please help me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25618201/how-to-enable-auto-complete-intellisense-for-ndk-in-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

You can change Android.mk in jni/png.

```
LOCAL_PATH  := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := lodepng
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := lodepng.c
# LOCAL_C_INCLUDES  := $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -DLODEPNG_NO_COMPILE_ENCODER -DLODEPNG_NO_COMPILE_DISK - DLODEPNG_NO_COMPILE_ANCILLARY_CHUNKS -DLODEPNG_NO_COMPILE_CPP
#include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
include $(PREBUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

This module should be used as a prebuild static library.

Comment: `include $(PREBUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)` Didn't do anything, it didn't even compiled `liblodepng.a` this time, and I couldn't find any info of it on the web.
Did you meant `include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)` instead? In this second case, it tells me that the file should point to a `.a` file...